# Is it possible to remove an entry's Expiration Date?

Tags: entries, postdate

Once I have given an entry an expiration date, is there any way to delete that date so that it never expires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just empty the expiration date and time field and save the entry. Or do you want to do it in a plugin (using PHP)?

Comment: Yes I can. For some reason this obvious solution wasn't working for me, but now it is.